# Знак доллара, вместо имени переменной

Tags: javascript

Читая код, встретился с такой записью:

```
$.on('command', function(event) {
  //Code there...
}
```

Собственно, вопрос: как понимать название переменной (ранее не объявленной), состоящее только из знака доллара?

Comment: Чудес не бывает, кто-то этот доллар объявил. Покажите больше кода.

Comment: Это фрагмент кода, написанный на JS под Node, необходимый для работы irc бота. Если это чем-либо может помочь.

Comment: https://github.com/phantomindex/PhantomBot-Custom-Scripts/blob/master/chatvote/chatevoteCommand.js

Comment: https://github.com/PhantomBot/PhantomBot

Comment: Первая ссылка - на фрагмент кода. Вторая на бота, под которого эти скрипты были написаны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тот проект, который вы смотрите, называется "PhantomBot-Custom-Scripts". Как следует из названия, это скрипты, которые подгружаются в PhantomBot. Очевидно, этот самый доллар является частью PhantomBot API, объявлен в нем и предоставляется загрузчиком скриптов.

Вот код реализации этого "доллара":
https://github.com/PhantomBot/PhantomBot/blob/master/source/me/mast3rplan/phantombot/script/ScriptApi.java

А вот то место, где он "подключается":
https://github.com/PhantomBot/PhantomBot/blob/30f052be6a8f294a0a77b7c48dd562371e085e0d/source/me/mast3rplan/phantombot/script/Script.java#L79

PS зря вы добавили тэг `node.js`, он сбивает с толку. PhantomBot использует [`Rhino`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino).

Comment: Благодарю! Теперь я разобрался.